# Why can't I easily open web browsers from the terminal application?

Tags: macos, terminal

In order to run Chrome from the Terminal application, I have to do

```
open -a "Google Chrome" index.html
```

rather than just something like "chrome index.html".

The same also seems to be true for Firefox.

It's not because I can't open any GUI applications from the command line. For example, I can do `mate .` to open TextMate.

What's the rationale for web browsers not having a command like "chrome index.html"?

Comment: Did you see my updated answer?

Comment: NB mate is not a GUI application. It is a commandeline executable that happens to call a GUI app. ie mate is the exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To open a application from the terminal it has to be in one of the paths of your `$PATH` environnement variable.

By default `/Application/` where Chrome is located is not in your path. Therefore you can't launch an application without giving the full path to your app.

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome http://google.com
```

Will work.

Comment: It will work however you cannot then close Terminal without also closing Google Chrome.  In this case using `open -a Google Chrome` is the proper way as it's process is not terminated when closing the Terminal.

Comment: @user3439894, Isn't `.app` needed?

Comment: @Pacerier, First let me start by saying the command I posted in the comment should have been `open -a Google\ Chrome` or `open -a 'Google Chrome'` and no, .app is not needed. Read the manual page for the [**`open`**](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/open.1.html) _command_. You'll see examples for an application where .app is used and not used for an application. So either works, and I'm not going to type 4 extra characters when they are not needed. :)

Answer (score 4):

It's probably safe to say that most Mac users do not open GUI apps via the CLI, which is why most GUI apps do not include the CLI support like TextMate does.  In other words, TextMate actually includes a binary executable named `mate` which is installed in `$PATH`, which is why one does not need to preface it with the `open` command like opening a GUI app which does not include that type of CLI support.

If you want to emulate that behavior then create a script named `chrome` placed in the `$PATH`, typically `/usr/local/bin/` for something such as this.

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -n "$1" ]; then
    open -a "Google Chrome" "$1"
else
    open -a "Google Chrome"
fi
```

Save the above code in a plain text file named `chrome` and make it executable by:

`chmod +x chrome`

Then you can start Google Chrome via CLI by `chrome` or `chrome URL` where `URL` is properly formatted if not just a filename in the `$PWD`.